# 'Unable to find component class 'FocusPoint_FocusPoint' - Craft CMS 3 Migrating from Focus Point Fields

Tags: craft3, image, plugin-focuspoint, focal-point

I am migrating from Craft 2 to Craft 3 where images have Focus Point fields.

I've followed Dan Hoerr's FocalPoint Migration ([migration guide](https://github.com/ad-dc/focalpoint_migration))
And the php migrate script seems to have run successfully, however entries are still showing:

[image: Unable to find component class 'FocusPoint_FocusPoint'.]

Opening the field under Settings > Fields > Matrix Block > Image shows:

[image: The field type "FocusPoint_FocusPoint” could not be found.]

How do I remove old FocusPoint field data and regain these image fields?
Will I need to manually re-add all the images?

I have tried:

- Clearing Caches
- Updating asset indexes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The migration script only converts your existing focal points as good as it can (see the repo description) but doesn't convert the fields. Since the settings that were stored in your field are now in the assets you can savely convert those fields to asset fields